# Downcasting C++ Objects

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism

I have a base class (which is not abstract) which defines methods that its subclasses inherit. I have another program which has an methods that have as output the an object of the base class type.

```
class A {
   //methods
};
class B : public A {
   //more methods
};

A function() { //return some instance of A}
```

I want to define functions in terms of object A but then use them for object B. E.g.

```
B obj = function()
```

I've looked into dynamic casts, but that seems to require I cast pointers. Is there any way to down-cast instances of objects without using pointers?

Comment: That's not downcasting I think (B to A would be downcasting). Did you mean upcasting? Or something.

Comment: There is no downcasting of objects. Polymorphism only works through pointers or references. You can downcast those, if the dynamic type is right. This is strongly not recommended though.

Comment: You can't dynamically add stuff to an object (looks to me like that's what you are trying to do) - C++ doesn't work that way.

Comment: This *can* work if `B` can be constructed from an instance of `A`, effectively converting an `A` instance to a `B` instance. That is, `B` provides a constructor of the signature `B(A const &)`.

Answer (score 2):

No.

You are trying to give an object something it does not have.

Comment: The wording is a bit misleading: of course, we give an object something it does not have - there is no point in giving an object something it already has!

Comment: The example is what I worked on. Return an A but call it a B

Comment: Probably "pretending an object is something it actually isn't" sounds better?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to down-cast instances of objects without using pointers?

You can down cast references as well, so technically you don't need pointers.

---

You can convert a base class object to a derived type if the derived type has a converting constructor. For example, you might copy-construct the base subobject:

```
struct B : A {
   B(const A& a): A(a) {}
};
// ...
B obj = function();
```

However, this is not "down casting", which is *"the act of casting a **reference** of a base class to one of its derived classes."* (quote from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting), emphasis mine). In the quoted context, reference is a more general term that encompasses references, pointers and other indirection.

Comment: That is not casting. It is construction

Comment: @EdHeal casting involves construction. Cast is an explicit conversion. A conversion results in a new object (possibly temporary that can be optimized away). It might be worth mentioning that if you cast a pointer `T*` to `U*`, there is no `U` object constructed, but a `U*`. When you cast a `T` to `U`, an instance of `U` is constructed.

Comment: @EdHeal It is construction via casting. Constructors for type X that accept a single argument of type Y (or something implicitly convertible to Y) and are not marked `explicit` are candidates for implicit conversion from a value of type Y to a value of type X. Given just the above code (and a type `A` that is default-constructible), `A a; B b = static_cast<B>(a);` would compile, for example -- and you don't even need the `static_cast` invocation. B's constructor is used to satisfy the cast.